# Apache console flashing constantly

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

I have an apache console running in windows which when running causes another command prompt window to flash open and close every second or so.  Is it normal for apache to behave in this manner?  Is there a way to run console mode with out this annoying flashing?

We are running windows xp and apache 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is spawning CGI windows. Maybe you need to uncheck 'Interact with desktop' for the apache service